# error to install react app in the hyperterminal

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, hyperterminal

How to solve this error?

I run npx create-react-app my-app

and get the error below:[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to poor network connection, Try to install the react app with a stable network